# Extract image from local folder through json in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am extracting images from a local image present in my system through Json. The Json file is:

```
"BackgroundImage": [
    "C:/Users/SS1/Downloads/images/black_background.jpg",
     "C:/Users/SS1/Downloads/images/Clipboard.png"
],
```

Is it possible to omit "C:/Users/SS1" so Unity only extracts a folder from the system irrespective of which computer it is?

Thanks,
Saif

Comment: its only text, so only store the relative folder link

Comment: It would change if I upload it to my Android phone and other devices. And so I really need JSON to load textures, videos and so on.

Comment: You're missing the point, the json only contains text value of the name of the file, dont send a local full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a full path, but a relative path and store the files in/using [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html). Then you can load the assets from the path from most platforms without having problems. You should not store these files anywhere else but alongside your game build.

You can also use the [application data path](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) as well but streaming assets is the recommended method.

Answer (score 2):

`Directory.GetFiles()` takes in a relative *or* a an absolute path. Just put a relative path from the root of the project and then pass it into the relative methods. Alternatively you could just store the file name in the JSON file and then use the application execution path to find the folder using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

e.g

```
var fileNames = getFileNamesFromJsonData();

foreach(var fileName in fileNames) {
    var absolutePath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/images/{fileName}";
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads